# xcode, iOS, XML document parsing

Tags: xml, ios, xcode

I am developing an iPad app on Xcode 4.2 for iOS 5.

In some cases in my app I need to do a sync call to a web service. So I get a SOAP response synchronously, which I need to parse to get the result.

I cannot use the event-driven XML parser `NSXMLParser`, since I need to return a sync result. Given that I cannot use `NSXMLDocument` on iOS, I am searching the SOAP response for the `CallMethodResult` and /`CallMethodResult` tags. The text between these tags is the result I need.

But if that result should be *`Tom & Jerry`*, the result in the XML is *`Tom & amp; Jerry`*. If I could use a nice XML document parser it would handle conversion of *`& amp;`* for me. I can do search and replaces to fix the resulting string, of course, but I hope I don't have to *reinvent the wheel*.

My result may contain any number of XML-unfriendly characters that would be fixed by an XML parser, so my conversion code could get quite long.

What's the best way to extract node info from XML without going down the event-driven route?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I cannot use the event-driven XML parser NSXMLParser, since I need to return a sync result

By 'sync', do you mean synchronous?

If so, you can still use `NSXMLParser`. Despite being event-driven, it is synchronous. The `- (BOOL)parse` method does not return until the parsing is complete.

Comment: I must have made the assumption that because it's event driven it runs on its own thread, thereby getting its answer in the parser didEndElement method. Very grateful for your advice.

Comment: I had no idea XML parsing was synchronous. It it blocking the UI when running on the main thread though?

Comment: Yup, it blocks. You could run it on a background thread in order to not block UI, if you're parsing big enough documents for the slowdown to be noticeable.